How can I attempt to row-compress a table type?
The documentation for row compression states that it has "No effect." on table types. This suggests that it's possible to attempt it, but ineffective. How can it be attempted? I find it impossible to imagine how to even try. As far as I know, you can only row compress a table and tables cannot contain table types.

Hmmm if you put it in the inline index definition you get 'data_compression' is not a recognized CREATE TYPE option. https://dbfiddle.uk/5R0FXvt3 Make a Pull Request on Github to change the docs to Not possible
